# what is cdn prefix instead of www in web address

Tags: http, dns, prefix, tld, webaddress

In place of a missing `www` prefix I sometimes see `cdn`.

Is this for a special service or program, different from a webserver ? Is there a list of all common leftmost subdomains/domain prefixes?

Answer (score 1):

cdn stands for content delivery network mainly used for application services (such as cloud based services from Google or Microsoft).  I don't know of any list out there for all of the prefixes, but there may be one that I haven't ran across yet.